# NullPointerException while loading images from Parse

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I want to download the images from Parse cloud and load them into map icon. I am using Picasso to convert the images into bitmap. I am working with map for the first time I am not sure if my method correct to load the images into map icons. Please somebody help me!

```
  markerOpts =
                markerOpts.title(post.getText());
          String uri = post.getImage().getUrl();
          final MarkerOptions finalMarkerOpts = markerOpts;
          Picasso.with(context)
                  .load(uri)
                  .into(new Target() {
                    @Override
                    public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
            /* Save the bitmap or do something with it here */

                      //Set it in the ImageView
                      finalMarkerOpts.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

                    }
                  });
        //  }
          // Add a new marker
          Marker marker = mapFragment.getMap().addMarker(markerOpts);
          mapMarkers.put(post.getObjectId(), marker);
        //  if (post.getObjectId().equals(selectedPostObjectId)) {
         //   marker.showInfoWindow();
           // selectedPostObjectId = null;
      //   }
        }
        // Clean up old markers.
        cleanUpMarkers(toKeep);
      }
    });
  }
```

Parse Model

```
 public ParseFile getImage(){
    return getParseFile("Image");
  }
```

Logcat:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.parse.ParseFile.getUrl()' on a null object reference
                                                                       at com.google.mywall.MainActivity$2.done(MainActivity.java:688)
                                                                       at com.google.mywall.MainActivity$2.done(MainActivity.java:627)
```

Comment: post logcat trash here.

Comment: `post.getImage().getUrl();` check this and put try catch for that.

Comment: @Clara how do i create a log for parsefile?

Answer (score 1):

You have not getting any values in post.getImage().getUrl();
So you are getting nullPointerException.
Did you correctly parsed the setImage();

Comment: I have added the image directly in the parse cloud

Comment: Directly set the image url to String uri, and check whether you have getting the same error again.